# "Employees, including young ones who profess to caring about DEI…" Why "caring"?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, predicate-frames, gerunds-vs-participles

> Employees, including young ones who profess to caring about DEI, may also put material concerns ahead of moral ones if the job market tightens.

Why is *caring* used, instead of care or be caring? is that correct grammar wise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13102/interested-in-knowing-versus-interested-to-know).

Comment: "profess to X" is sometimes used with a noun, maybe by analogy with "confess to". You can debate whether it's correct, but generally "profess NOUN" without "to" or "profess to INFINITIVE" seem to be preferred. Why? Who knows. Look at the usage examples in dictionaries.

Comment: If this is a quote, please indicate where it is taken from.

Answer (score 4):

Good question. Unfortunately this isn't one we can answer. By all appearances, it's a mistake. The correct expression would either use "care" or omit the word "to".

Comment: The construction is common enough in my experience that I would be surprised to find it is a mistake. Can you find references which support your statement?

Comment: You commonly see "to <participle>" used as an infinitive?  Infinitives in English should use the present tense form of the verb and not present participle, and the word "to" as given servers no other purpose here other than an erroneous attempt to express the infinitive "to care".

Comment: @Peter Yes, it's a mistake. Using *profess to GERUND* [is so rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=profess+to+believe%2Cprofess+to+believing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) it's jarring and weird. Plus [the OED says](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/profess_v) that it takes an infinitive object only: “II.3.a. 1530– *transitive*. To make profession of, to lay claim to (often with implication of insincerity); to make protestation of (some quality or feeling). Also **with infinitive as object: *to*** claim or pretend (to be or to do something).”